# parsing into several vector members

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, wavefront

I want to recursively parse a string and store the results in one struct. I've written a parser that can handle one iteration. The input is formatted as follows:

```
v  1.5 2.0 2.5
v  3.0 3.5 4.0
f 1 2 3
f 4 5 6 
v  4.5 5.0 5.5
v  6.0 6.5 7.0
f 7 8 9
f 10 11 12
```

The problem is that it only parses the first 4 lines, it stops at the third encountered 'v'. The complete code is given below. How do I modify this code so it also parses the rest of the input into the same struct? I've tried modifying the start rule from `start = vertex >> elements` to `start = *(vertex >> elements)`, but that only gives a huge compilation error. Same goes for `start = +(vertex >> elements)`. Any ideas how I should modify the rules?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

#include "boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp"
#include "boost/spirit/include/support_iso8859_1.hpp"
#include "boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp"


struct ElemParseData
{
    std::vector<float> verts;
    std::vector<unsigned int> idx;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    ElemParseData,
    (std::vector<float>, verts)
    (std::vector<unsigned int>, idx)
)


bool doParse( ElemParseData &parseData, const std::string &data )
{
    namespace qi      = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace iso8859 = boost::spirit::iso8859_1;

    struct objGram : qi::grammar<std::string::const_iterator, ElemParseData(), iso8859::space_type>
    {
        objGram() : objGram::base_type(start)
        {
            vertex   = *('v' >> qi::double_ >> qi::double_ >> qi::double_);
            elements = *('f' >> qi::int_ >> qi::int_ >> qi::int_);

            start = vertex >> elements;
        }

        qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, ElemParseData(), iso8859::space_type> start;
        qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, std::vector<float>(), iso8859::space_type> vertex;
        qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, std::vector<unsigned int>(), iso8859::space_type> elements;

    } objGrammar;

    std::string::const_iterator f = data.cbegin();
    bool res = qi::phrase_parse( f, data.cend(), objGrammar, iso8859::space, parseData );


    // print everything that hasn't been processed by the parser
    std::cout << "#### Trail ####" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::string(f, data.cend()) << std::endl;

    return res;
}


int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::filebuf fb;
    if ( fb.open("parsetest.txt", std::ios::in) )
    {
        std::istream is(&fb);
        while (is)
            ss << char(is.get());
        fb.close();
    }


    ElemParseData parseData;
    bool res = doParse( parseData, ss.str() );


    // print results
    std::cout << std::endl << "Parsing result: " << res << std::endl;
    std::cout << "---######### ResultData #########---" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "---- Begin vertex data ----" << std::endl;
    std::vector<float>::iterator it;
    for ( it = parseData.verts.begin(); it != parseData.verts.end(); ++it )
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    std::cout << "---- End vertex data ----" << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "---- Begin index data ----" << std::endl;
    std::vector<unsigned int>::iterator idxIt;
    for ( idxIt = parseData.idx.begin(); idxIt != parseData.idx.end(); ++idxIt )
            std::cout << *idxIt << std::endl;
    std::cout << "---- End index data ----" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Press enter to exit" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

P.S.: If needed, the compilation error can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/c7Z5A25j).

EDIT: I'm trying to write an Wavefront .OBJ parser. The input given here is just a simplification of my problem.

Comment: Why is there a need to recursively parse?  Looks like iteration would be simpler.

Comment: I want recursion, because I do not know how many times 'v' and 'f' repeat. 'v' and 'f' always follow each other, but this combination can occur an infinite amount of time (theoretically)

Comment: Still iteration fits the bill: it's a simple loop of either vertices or indices :) See my answer, of course

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several ways :)

1. Custom attribute traits
2. The same using semantic actions
3. Everything in semantic actions, at detail level

### 1. Custom attribute traits

The cleanest, IMO would to replace the Fusion Sequence Adaptation (`BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT`) by custom container attribute traits for Spirit:

```
namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace traits {

    template<> 
        struct is_container<ElemParseData, void> : mpl::true_ { };
    template<> 
        struct container_value<ElemParseData, void> { 
             typedef boost::variant<float, unsigned int> type;
        };
    template <>
        struct push_back_container<ElemParseData, std::vector<float>, void> {
            static bool call(ElemParseData& c, std::vector<float> const& val) {
                c.verts.insert(c.verts.end(), val.begin(), val.end());
                return true;
            }
        };
    template <>
        struct push_back_container<ElemParseData, std::vector<unsigned int>, void> {
            static bool call(ElemParseData& c, std::vector<unsigned int> const& val) {
                c.idx.insert(c.idx.end(), val.begin(), val.end());
                return true;
            }
        };
}}}
```

Without changes to the grammar, this will simply result in the same effect. However, now you can modify the parser to expect the desired grammar:

```
    vertex   = 'v' >> qi::double_ >> qi::double_ >> qi::double_;
    elements = 'f' >> qi::int_ >> qi::int_ >> qi::int_;

    start = *(vertex | elements);
```

And because of the traits, Spirit will "just know" how to insert into `ElemParseData`. See it **[live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=ad1a42fa5fa755a038c1c9cafd976bb7-82a7cbf86a70a71c98899cfeeff3e107)**

### 2. The same using semantic actions

You can wire it up in semantic actions:

```
    start = *(  
               vertex   [phx::bind(insert, _val, _1)] 
             | elements [phx::bind(insert, _val, _1)]
             );
```

With `insert` a member of type `inserter`:

```
struct inserter {
    template <typename,typename> struct result { typedef void type; };

    template <typename Attr, typename Vec>
        void operator()(Attr& attr, Vec const& v) const { dispatch(attr, v); }
    private:
    static void dispatch(ElemParseData& data, std::vector<float> vertices) {
        data.verts.insert(data.verts.end(), vertices.begin(), vertices.end());
    }
    static void dispatch(ElemParseData& data, std::vector<unsigned int> indices) {
        data.idx.insert(data.idx.end(), indices.begin(), indices.end());
    }
};
```

This looks largely the same, and it does the same: **[live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=30a39ea659000b6ed73a419119f7f606-82a7cbf86a70a71c98899cfeeff3e107)**

### 3. Everything in semantic actions, at detail level

This is the only solution that doesn't require any kind of plumbing, except perhaps inclusion of `boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp`:

```
struct objGram : qi::grammar<std::string::const_iterator, ElemParseData(), iso8859::space_type>
{
    objGram() : objGram::base_type(start)
    {
        using namespace qi;

        auto add_vertex = phx::push_back(phx::bind(&ElemParseData::verts, _r1), _1);
        auto add_index  = phx::push_back(phx::bind(&ElemParseData::idx,   _r1), _1);
        vertex   = 'v' >> double_ [add_vertex] >> double_ [add_vertex] >> double_ [add_vertex];
        elements = 'f' >> int_    [add_index]  >> int_    [add_index]  >> int_    [add_index] ;

        start = *(vertex(_val) | elements(_val));
    }

    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, ElemParseData(), iso8859::space_type> start;
    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, void(ElemParseData&), iso8859::space_type> vertex, elements;
} objGrammar;
```

Note:

- One slight **advantage** here would be that there is less copying of values
- A disadvantage is that you lose 'atomicity' (if a *line* fails to parse after, say, the second value, the first two values will have been pushed into the `ElemParseData` members irrevocably).

> ## Side note
>
> There is a bug in the read loop, prefer the simpler options:
>
> ```
> std::filebuf fb;
> if (fb.open("parsetest.txt", std::ios::in))
> {
>     ss << &fb;
>     fb.close();
> }
> ```
>
> Or consider `boost::spirit::istream_iterator`

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you :). Those traits look interesting. I will look into those some more, see what other cool things I can do with it. About your side note: can you please tell me what the bug is? I don't really see it.. It's about the char cast isn't it?...

Comment: @KrienLinnenbank I just added two more approaches, in decreasing levels of encapsulation. The latter may have some interesting performance characteristics. However, see this: **[Boost Spirit: “Semantic actions are evil”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)**

Comment: And option **3.** live on **[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=6ffa584b2cbd63e7ee5e62a2c21fdf57-82a7cbf86a70a71c98899cfeeff3e107)** as well. About the bug: it was a spurious character being read _after_ EOF

Comment: @sehe - Krien mentioned that he tried something like this: vertex = *('v' >> qi::double_ >> qi::double_ >> qi::double_);
            elements = *('f' >> qi::int_ >> qi::int_ >> qi::int_);
start = *(vertex >> elements); if I omit attribute propagation to `start` - any explanation why this cannot work?

Comment: @sehe Your answers have always been great, but lately they are simply amazing. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:85371+[boost-spirit] is a great learning resource about spirit.

Comment: @G.Civardi The problem is that the attribute that you get from that starting rule is basically std::vector<ElemParseData>. This approach should work if Krien changed the rule signature, passed a vector to `phrase_parse` and then "flattened" the vector into a single ElemParseData. But that is extra work compared to "simply" adding the specializations sehe recommends.

Comment: @cv_and_he - I tried to solve the task using semantic actions (similar approach as sehe/2) but I used the rules as I stated above .. Everything compiled fine but during parsing it was endless loop. I would like to understand why it is happening... :-)

Comment: @cv_and_he Indeed, I also managed to get that working before I asked the question, but the extra work concatenating the vectors didn't seem like the "right" way to do it..

Comment: @cv_and_he [indeed it does](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=58a815531443edd5e482396b46941a42-82a7cbf86a70a71c98899cfeeff3e107) (but given slightly changed Spirit Traits). And thanks for the kind words. I'm a little surprised, though, because I've always been gleaning the 'advanced' bits from you :/

Comment: @sehe Do you do anything special to compile spirit code successfully on coliru? The times I've tried, even with really simple programs, it has always timed out.

Comment: @cv_and_he yeah, sorry; I know the author and maintainer there (he's a [lounger](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec) and he kindly gave me a backdoor to raise the compilation time limits... I'm sure I could tell you, but not here :( It's such a shame that http://liveworkspace.org/ is still "Temporarily under maintenance"

Comment: @sehe No problem, it was simply curiosity. I'm sure that you will help lots of people with that. There is nothing better than a quick demo, especially with code that is usually hard to read.