# Several matches in a one pass parser?

Tags: boost, boost-spirit

I am trying (yet) to populate several vectors with data parsed from a log. The key is do it as fast and efficient as possible, so I would like to collect all the data in only one pass (not "or" between rules).

I have found the next problems:

1) Every time I use spirit and it does not work as expected I find myself totally loss and trying test and error for two hours. Is there any debug directive that gives some hint about what has gone wrong?

2) Is it valid the way I use phoenix construct? I mean, can it be used as I have done in code for avoiding using a symbol table?

3) Is there any way of getting info for a rule and using it into another rule? I have tried with phoenix::ref but it confuses data when using combined with BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT.

4) Am I making a deep error using code as this? I mean, should I use a grammar wrapping this with auto rules or just simplify using two rules one for "location" and other for "location + event" and then using phoenix?

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_seek.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/phoenix.hpp>
#include <cstring> // strlen

typedef char const* It;
enum kind { SLOPE, GEAR };

struct Location {
    int driver;
    double time;
    double vel;
    double km;
    std::string date;
    std::string road;
};

struct Event {
    int event;
    double time;
    double value;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Location, date, time, driver, vel, road, km)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Event, event, value)//Same "time" as its previous "Location" header. Please do not adapt "time" unless necesssary.


//They shall be defined in another compilation unit and defined as extern in production code. Please do not insert within dispatcher struct.
std::vector<Location> container1;
std::vector<Event> container2;

struct dispatcher
{
    static void add(const Location& loc) { container1.push_back(loc); }
    static void add(const Event& ev)     { container2.push_back(ev);  }
};

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace px = boost::phoenix;

namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace traits
{
    template <> struct is_container<dispatcher> : std::true_type { };

    template <> struct container_value<dispatcher>
    {
        typedef boost::variant<Location, Event> type;
    };

    template <typename T> struct push_back_container<dispatcher, T>
    {
        struct Visitor
        {
            typedef void result_type;
            template <typename U> void operator()(U const& ev) const { dispatcher::add(ev); }
        };

        static bool call(dispatcher& log, T const& attribute)
        {
            boost::apply_visitor(Visitor(), attribute);
            return true;
        }
    };
} } }

void parse_test_1(It b, It e) {
    using namespace qi;

    auto date = copy(
        repeat(4)[digit] >> '-' >> repeat(3)[alpha] >> '-' >> repeat(2)[digit] >> ' ' >> 
        repeat(2)[digit] >> ':' >> repeat(2)[digit] >> ':' >> repeat(2)[digit] >> '.' >> +digit);

    qi::rule<It, Event()> slope = lit(" - SLOPE: ")[px::construct<int>(kind::SLOPE)] >> double_;
    qi::rule<It, Event()> gear = lit(" - GEAR: ")[px::construct<int>(kind::GEAR)] >> double_;

    qi::rule<It, Location()> line = '[' >> raw[date] >> "] - "
        >> double_ >> " s"
        >> " => Driver: "  >> int_
        >> " - Speed: "    >> double_
        >> " - Road: "     >> raw[+graph]
        >> " - Km: "       >> double_
        >> -(slope | gear)
        >> (eol | eoi);

    parse(b, e, *boost::spirit::repository::qi::seek[line], dispatcher());
}

void parse_test_2(It b, It e) {
    using namespace qi;

    double t = 0;
    auto date = copy(
        repeat(4)[digit] >> '-' >> repeat(3)[alpha] >> '-' >> repeat(2)[digit] >> ' ' >> 
        repeat(2)[digit] >> ':' >> repeat(2)[digit] >> ':' >> repeat(2)[digit] >> '.' >> +digit);

    qi::rule<It, Event()> slope = lit(" - SLOPE: ")[px::construct<int>(kind::SLOPE)] >> double_;
    qi::rule<It, Event()> gear = lit(" - GEAR: ")[px::construct<int>(kind::GEAR)] >> double_;

    qi::rule<It, Location()> line = '[' >> raw[date] >> "] - "
        >> double_ >> " s"
        >> " => Driver: "  >> int_
        >> " - Speed: "    >> double_
        >> " - Road: "     >> raw[+graph]
        >> " - Km: "       >> double_
        >> -(slope | gear)
        >> (eol | eoi);

    parse(b, e, *line, dispatcher());
}

//Not all the lines will match the parser!
static char input1[] = 
"[2018-Mar-13 13:13:59.580482] - 0.200 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.0 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90.0 - SLOPE: 5.5\n\
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.170203] - 1.790 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.0 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90.0 - GEAR: 1\n\
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.170203] - 1.790 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.1 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90.0\n\
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.170203] - 1.790 s => I do not care about this line\n\
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.819966] - 2.440 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.1 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90.0\n\
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.170203] - 2.440 s => Neither I do about this other line\n\
[2018-Mar-13 13:15:01.819966] - 3.440 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.2 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90.0 - SLOPE: 10\n";

static const size_t len1 = strlen(input1);

//All the lines shall match the parser!
static char input2[] = 
"[2018-Mar-13 13:13:59.580482] - 0.200 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.0 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90.0 - SLOPE: 5.5\n\
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.170203] - 1.790 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.0 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90.0 - GEAR: 1\n\
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.170203] - 1.790 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.1 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90.0\n\
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.819966] - 2.440 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.1 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90.0\n\
[2018-Mar-13 13:15:01.819966] - 3.440 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.2 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90.0 - SLOPE: 10\n";

static const size_t len2 = strlen(input2);

int main()
{
    parse_test_1(input1, input1+len1);
    std::cout << "TEST 1:\n";
    std::cout << "Locations:\n";
    std::for_each(std::begin(container1), std::end(container1), [](const Location& loc)
    {
        std::cout << "[" << loc.date << "] - " << loc.time << " s => Driver: " << loc.driver << " - Speed: " << loc.vel << " - Road: " << loc.road << " - Km: " << loc.km << std::endl;
    });

    std::cout << "Events:\n";
    std::for_each(std::begin(container2), std::end(container2), [](const Event& ev)
    {
        std::cout << ev.time << " s => EVENT(" << ev.event << ") : " << ev.value << std::endl;
    });

    container1.clear();
    container2.clear();

    parse_test_2(input2, input2+len2);
    std::cout << "\nTEST 2:\n";
    std::cout << "Locations:\n";
    std::for_each(std::begin(container1), std::end(container1), [](const Location& loc)
    {
        std::cout << "[" << loc.date << "] - " << loc.time << " s => Driver: " << loc.driver << " - Speed: " << loc.vel << " - Road: " << loc.road << " - Km: " << loc.km << std::endl;
    });

    std::cout << "Events:\n";
    std::for_each(std::begin(container2), std::end(container2), [](const Event& ev)
    {
        std::cout << ev.time << " s => EVENT(" << ev.event << ") : " << ev.value << std::endl;
    });

    return 0;
}
```

RESULT: The expected result should be this one:

```
TEST 1:
Locations:
[2018-Mar-13 13:13:59.580482] - 0.2 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.170203] - 1.79 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.170203] - 1.79 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.1 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.819966] - 2.44 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.1 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90
[2018-Mar-13 13:15:01.819966] - 3.44 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.2 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90
Events:
0.2 s => EVENT(0): 5.5
1.79 s => EVENT(1): 1
3.44 s => EVENT(0): 10

TEST 2:
Locations:
[2018-Mar-13 13:13:59.580482] - 0.2 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.170203] - 1.79 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.170203] - 1.79 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.1 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.819966] - 2.44 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.1 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90
[2018-Mar-13 13:15:01.819966] - 3.44 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.2 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90
Events:
0.2 s => EVENT(0): 5.5
1.79 s => EVENT(1): 1
3.44 s => EVENT(0): 10
```

Comment: In response to number "4)" that sounds like a plan. You already have the rule to parse it [from the _"Generalize: Common Fields and Other Events"_ example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49312362/85371), so make it event driven and convert into whatever proprietary library globals you need to convert from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First off: *I gave you **all** of that in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49312362/85371), under "Separate vectors with a trait". The only difference appears to be the types and the fact that you made `LogEvents` members global variables (ick).*

On to your question code:

```
 parse(b, e, *boost::spirit::repository::qi::seek[line], dispatcher());
```

Why are you passing the dispatcher there? Dispatcher is not a compatible attribute (in fact has only static non-data members).

So, let's fix it back to a sane data structure (instead of global variables):

```
struct ParsedData
{
    std::vector<Location> _locations;
    std::vector<Event> _events;
    void add(const Location& loc) { _locations.push_back(loc); }
    void add(const Event& ev)     { _events.push_back(ev);  }
};
```

Note that the containers [aren't global any more](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad) and they [have proper names](http://wiki.c2.com/?GoodVariableNames).

The `boost::spirit::traits` specializations are the same (*mutatis mutandis*) except that we now have a data instance, so we bind it (again, as in [the original example linked above, line 52](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3068ab6e7064798), so let's fix the usage:

```
ParsedData data;
parse(b, e, *boost::spirit::repository::qi::seek[line], data);
return data;
```

From here, it all worked.

### Further Cleanup And Demo

Notes:

- there is no reason to use raw char arrays and strlen in C++ (I used `std::string`)
- there is no reason to duplicate all the code and name everything `_1` or `_2`. I made main:

  ```
  int main() {
      do_test("TEST 1", input1, parse_test_1);
      do_test("TEST 2", input2, parse_test_2);
  }
  ```
- there is no reason to use `for_each` with a lambda where a ranged-for would suffice. This is `do_test`:

  ```
  void do_test(std::string caption, std::string const& input, ParsedData(*f)(It,It)) {
      ParsedData const data = f(input.begin(), input.end());
      std::cout << caption << ":\n";
      std::cout << "Locations:\n";
      for (Location const& loc : data._locations) {
          std::cout << "[" << loc.date << "] - " << loc.time << " s => Driver: " << loc.driver << " - Speed: " << loc.vel << " - Road: " << loc.road << " - Km: " << loc.km << std::endl;
      }

      std::cout << "Events:\n";
      for (Event const& ev : data._events) {
          std::cout << " EVENT(" << ev.event << ") : " << ev.value << std::endl;
      }
  }
  ```
- I dropped the `time` member from `Event` since it was unused.

### Full Listing

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e45dcf160b677aca)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_seek.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/phoenix.hpp>
#include <cstring> // strlen

typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
enum kind { SLOPE, GEAR };

struct Location {
    int driver;
    double time;
    double vel;
    double km;
    std::string date;
    std::string road;
};

struct Event {
    int event;
    double value;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Location, date, time, driver, vel, road, km)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Event, event, value)

struct ParsedData {
    std::vector<Location> _locations;
    std::vector<Event> _events;
    void add(const Location& loc) { _locations.push_back(loc); }
    void add(const Event& ev)     { _events.push_back(ev);  }
};

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace px = boost::phoenix;

namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace traits {
    template <> struct is_container<ParsedData> : std::true_type {};
    template <> struct container_value<ParsedData> { typedef boost::variant<Location, Event> type; };

    template <typename T> struct push_back_container<ParsedData, T> {
        struct Visitor {
            ParsedData &data;
            typedef void result_type;
            template <typename U> void operator()(U const &ev) const { data.add(ev); }
        };

        static bool call(ParsedData &log, T const &attribute) {
            boost::apply_visitor(Visitor{ log }, attribute);
            return true;
        }
    };
} } } // namespace boost::spirit::traits

ParsedData parse_test_1(It b, It e) {
    using namespace qi;

    auto date = copy(
        repeat(4)[digit] >> '-' >> repeat(3)[alpha] >> '-' >> repeat(2)[digit] >> ' ' >> 
        repeat(2)[digit] >> ':' >> repeat(2)[digit] >> ':' >> repeat(2)[digit] >> '.' >> +digit);

    qi::rule<It, Event()> slope = lit(" - SLOPE: ")[px::construct<int>(kind::SLOPE)] >> double_;
    qi::rule<It, Event()> gear = lit(" - GEAR: ")[px::construct<int>(kind::GEAR)] >> double_;

    qi::rule<It, Location()> line = '[' >> raw[date] >> "] - "
        >> double_ >> " s"
        >> " => Driver: "  >> int_
        >> " - Speed: "    >> double_
        >> " - Road: "     >> raw[+graph]
        >> " - Km: "       >> double_
        >> -(slope | gear)
        >> (eol | eoi);

    ParsedData data;
    parse(b, e, *boost::spirit::repository::qi::seek[line], data);
    return data;
}

ParsedData parse_test_2(It b, It e) {
    using namespace qi;

    auto date = copy(
        repeat(4)[digit] >> '-' >> repeat(3)[alpha] >> '-' >> repeat(2)[digit] >> ' ' >> 
        repeat(2)[digit] >> ':' >> repeat(2)[digit] >> ':' >> repeat(2)[digit] >> '.' >> +digit);

    qi::rule<It, Event()> slope = lit(" - SLOPE: ")[px::construct<int>(kind::SLOPE)] >> double_;
    qi::rule<It, Event()> gear = lit(" - GEAR: ")[px::construct<int>(kind::GEAR)] >> double_;

    qi::rule<It, Location()> line = '[' >> raw[date] >> "] - "
        >> double_ >> " s"
        >> " => Driver: "  >> int_
        >> " - Speed: "    >> double_
        >> " - Road: "     >> raw[+graph]
        >> " - Km: "       >> double_
        >> -(slope | gear)
        >> (eol | eoi);

    ParsedData data;
    parse(b, e, *line, data);
    return data;
}

//Not all the lines will match the parser!
static std::string const input1 = 
"[2018-Mar-13 13:13:59.580482] - 0.200 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.0 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90.0 - SLOPE: 5.5\n\
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.170203] - 1.790 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.0 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90.0 - GEAR: 1\n\
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.170203] - 1.790 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.1 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90.0\n\
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.170203] - 1.790 s => I do not care about this line\n\
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.819966] - 2.440 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.1 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90.0\n\
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.170203] - 2.440 s => Neither I do about this other line\n\
[2018-Mar-13 13:15:01.819966] - 3.440 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.2 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90.0 - SLOPE: 10\n";

//All the lines shall match the parser!
static std::string const input2 = 
"[2018-Mar-13 13:13:59.580482] - 0.200 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.0 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90.0 - SLOPE: 5.5\n\
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.170203] - 1.790 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.0 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90.0 - GEAR: 1\n\
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.170203] - 1.790 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.1 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90.0\n\
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.819966] - 2.440 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.1 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90.0\n\
[2018-Mar-13 13:15:01.819966] - 3.440 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.2 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90.0 - SLOPE: 10\n";

void do_test(std::string caption, std::string const& input, ParsedData(*f)(It,It)) {
    ParsedData const data = f(input.begin(), input.end());
    std::cout << caption << ":\n";
    std::cout << "Locations:\n";
    for (Location const& loc : data._locations) {
        std::cout << "[" << loc.date << "] - " << loc.time << " s => Driver: " << loc.driver << " - Speed: " << loc.vel << " - Road: " << loc.road << " - Km: " << loc.km << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Events:\n";
    for (Event const& ev : data._events) {
        std::cout << " EVENT(" << ev.event << ") : " << ev.value << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    do_test("TEST 1", input1, parse_test_1);
    do_test("TEST 2", input2, parse_test_2);
}
```

### Further Observations:

1. It is unclear to me when you'd expect the `Event` rules (slope/gear) to match or synthesize an attribute. It's also unclear to me why those would be optional (the location part of a line cannot possibly match without that part).
2. Also, the natural attribute exposed by a rule like

   ```
   qi::rule<It, Location()> line = '[' >> raw[date] >> "] - "
       >> double_ >> " s"
       >> " => Driver: "  >> int_
       >> " - Speed: "    >> double_
       >> " - Road: "     >> raw[+graph]
       >> " - Km: "       >> double_
       >> -(slope | gear)
       >> (eol | eoi);
   ```

   Would have Location contain an extra field:

   ```
   struct Location {
       int driver;
       double time;
       double vel;
       double km;
       std::string date;
       std::string road;
       boost::optional<Event> event;
   };

   BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Event, event, value)
   BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Location, date, time, driver, vel, road, km, event)
   ```
3. These rules are odd:

   ```
   qi::rule<It, Event()> slope = lit(" - SLOPE: ")[px::construct<int>(kind::SLOPE)] >> double_;
   qi::rule<It, Event()> gear = lit(" - GEAR: ")[px::construct<int>(kind::GEAR)] >> double_;
   ```

   Why not use the [`symbols` approach exactly as I showed in the linked answer (line 57/98)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bf3cce75c5d8432)? If you insist on doing it "clumsy", do **not** use semantic actions ([Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)) but use `qi::attr`:

   ```
   qi::rule<It, Event()> slope = " - SLOPE: " >> attr(kind::SLOPE) >> double_;
   qi::rule<It, Event()> gear = " - GEAR: " >> attr(kind::GEAR) >> double_;
   ```

   Among the helpful effects are that your compilation times can be cut in half, and also the attribute values actually propagate (your semantic actions had no effect at all, and actively suppressed automatic attribute propagation...).

With these improvements in place we get:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df96baa3d2aecaa7)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_seek.hpp>

typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
enum kind { SLOPE, GEAR };

struct Event {
    int event;
    double value;
};

struct Location {
    int driver;
    double time;
    double vel;
    double km;
    std::string date;
    std::string road;
    boost::optional<Event> event;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Event, event, value)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Location, date, time, driver, vel, road, km, event)

using ParsedData = std::vector<Location>;

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace px = boost::phoenix;

ParsedData parse_test(It b, It e) {
    using namespace qi;

    auto date = copy(
        repeat(4)[digit] >> '-' >> repeat(3)[alpha] >> '-' >> repeat(2)[digit] >> ' ' >> 
        repeat(2)[digit] >> ':' >> repeat(2)[digit] >> ':' >> repeat(2)[digit] >> '.' >> +digit);

    qi::rule<It, Event()> slope = " - SLOPE: " >> attr(kind::SLOPE) >> double_;
    qi::rule<It, Event()> gear = " - GEAR: " >> attr(kind::GEAR) >> double_;

    qi::rule<It, Location()> line = '[' >> raw[date] >> "] - "
        >> double_ >> " s"
        >> " => Driver: "  >> int_
        >> " - Speed: "    >> double_
        >> " - Road: "     >> raw[+graph]
        >> " - Km: "       >> double_
        >> -(slope | gear)
        >> (eol | eoi);

    ParsedData data;
    parse(b, e, *boost::spirit::repository::qi::seek[line], data);
    return data;
}

//Not all the lines will match the parser!
static std::string const input = 
"[2018-Mar-13 13:13:59.580482] - 0.200 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.0 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90.0 - SLOPE: 5.5\n\
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.170203] - 1.790 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.0 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90.0 - GEAR: 1\n\
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.170203] - 1.790 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.1 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90.0\n\
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.170203] - 1.790 s => I do not care about this line\n\
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.819966] - 2.440 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.1 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90.0\n\
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.170203] - 2.440 s => Neither I do about this other line\n\
[2018-Mar-13 13:15:01.819966] - 3.440 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.2 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90.0 - SLOPE: 10\n";

int main() {
    auto parsed = parse_test(input.begin(), input.end());
    std::cout << "Locations:\n";
    for (Location const& loc : parsed) {
        std::cout << "[" << loc.date << "] - " << loc.time << " s => Driver: " << loc.driver << " - Speed: " << loc.vel << " - Road: " << loc.road << " - Km: " << loc.km << std::endl;
        if (loc.event)
            std::cout << " - event: " << loc.event->event << " value: " << loc.event->value << "\n";
    }
}
```

Printing

```
Locations:
[2018-Mar-13 13:13:59.580482] - 0.2 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90
 - event: 0 value: 5.5
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.170203] - 1.79 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90
 - event: 1 value: 1
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.170203] - 1.79 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.1 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.1702032018-Mar-13 13:14:01.819966] - 2.44 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.1 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90
[2018-Mar-13 13:14:01.1702032018-Mar-13 13:15:01.819966] - 3.44 s => Driver: 0 - Speed: 0.2 - Road: A-11 - Km: 90
 - event: 0 value: 10
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation but your Coliru code does not match the expected output (the events vector still is empty) so I guess that problem is not so easy to solve in the way I have defined it.

Comment: It may seems that I am asking the same again, but it is not. Allow me to explain it: I must parse several thousands of logs files of about 20 different formats and I have used your earlier responses for some of them. All your observations are valid, but understand that some times you are limited by externalities, in my  case VS 2010 and boost 1.53 (weird, isn't it? Just a 2013 project update and a hard client). I would love use range fors and initializers lists, but sadly it is not possible. By the way, i neither would use a pointer to function in c++ any more since boost/std::function

Comment: Finally, after some benchmarking I have decided to use your boost::optional approach, so I "buy" it to you. It is a fast one pass parser while only penalized by a small over-use of memory. Again, thanks a lot for sharing your acknoledges and excuse me if I have not defined clearly the problem before.

Comment: I noted the fact that the `container2` was still empty in _"Further Observations"_, explaining why. I couldn't really change that without changing the behaviour.

Comment: Note also, you don't need `optional<>` much here, [changing `-(slope | gear)` to `(slope | gear | attr(Event{-1,0.0}))`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22555bd0cbf71e0f).

Comment: That's very similar to the [_"Generalize: Common Fields and Other Events"_ version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bf3cce75c5d8432) from the [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49312362/85371). Ironically, that one was still considerably more optimized using string-views to avoid all the allocations (!!), didn't use "optional" and parses strictly better/more. If you enabled debug mode, you would notice backtracking occurring due to both `seek[]` and the missed chance to use `symbols`. Backtracking hurts your sequential throughput.

Comment: So, if you I were you and you (seemingly) care about performance and memory usage, go BACK to the older answer. If you need help translating that to VS2010, ask about THAT.

Comment: So, [here's a minor variation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04fd22bb0c780f9f) that simplifies removing the variant and just ignores "other" lines, in pure c++03. That should be guaranteed to compile in VS2010. I'd still appreciate if you made _that_ a separate question, so I can post that with some explanations and more tweaks (parsing the input from your current question, e.g.  and possibly parsing the timestamp to a posix timestamp, instead of leaving it a string view)

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Sure I will do a separate question about that detailing the problem and its constraints, just let my find some time during easter vacations for it.