# Why does using a stream in boost spirit penalize performance so much?

Tags: boost, boost-spirit

I have prepared a small benchmark program for measuring different ways of parsing. The problem comes with the huge decrease in performance when using a stream and a custom function for storing a date as a time_t + double.

The weird boost spirit trait for std::string is because seek backtracking fills the variable string with all the common parts of non-matching lines until a line that matches is found.

Sorry for the source code quality (copy/paste, bad variable names, weak indentation...). I am aware that this benchmark code is not going to be included in Clean Code book, so please ignore this fact and let's focus on the subject.

I understand that the fastest way is using a string without backtracking, but time increment for stream is really strange. Can someone explain me what is going on?

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_seek.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono/chrono.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

typedef std::string::const_iterator It;

namespace structs {
    struct Timestamp {
        std::time_t date;
        double ms;

        friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& stream, Timestamp& time)
        {
            struct std::tm tm;

            if (stream >> std::get_time(&tm, "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S") >> time.ms)
                time.date = std::mktime(&tm);

            return stream;
        }
    };

    struct Record1 {
        std::string date;
        double time;
        std::string str;
    };

    struct Record2 {
        Timestamp date;
        double time;
        std::string str;
    };

    typedef std::vector<Record1> Records1;
    typedef std::vector<Record2> Records2;
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(structs::Record1,
        (std::string, date)
        (double, time)
        (std::string, str))

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(structs::Record2,
        (structs::Timestamp, date)
        (double, time)
        (std::string, str))

namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace traits {
    template <typename It>
    struct assign_to_attribute_from_iterators<std::string, It, void> {
        static inline void call(It f, It l, std::string& attr) {
            attr = std::string(&*f, std::distance(f,l));
        }
    };
} } }

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace QiParsers {
    template <typename It>
    struct Parser1 : qi::grammar<It, structs::Record1()>
    {
        Parser1() : Parser1::base_type(start) {
            using namespace qi;

            start = '[' >> raw[*~char_(']')] >> ']'
                >> " - " >> double_ >> " s"
                >> " => String: "  >> raw[+graph]
                >> eol;
        }

    private:
        qi::rule<It, structs::Record1()> start;
    };

    template <typename It>
    struct Parser2 : qi::grammar<It, structs::Record2()>
    {
        Parser2() : Parser2::base_type(start) {
            using namespace qi;

            start = '[' >> stream >> ']'
                >> " - " >> double_ >> " s"
                >> " => String: "  >> raw[+graph]
                >> eol;
        }

    private:
        qi::rule<It, structs::Record2()> start;
    };

    template <typename It>
    struct Parser3 : qi::grammar<It, structs::Records1()>
    {
        Parser3() : Parser3::base_type(start) {
            using namespace qi;
            using boost::phoenix::push_back;

            line = '[' >> raw[*~char_(']')] >> ']'
                >> " - " >> double_ >> " s"
                >> " => String: "  >> raw[+graph];

            ignore = *~char_("\r\n");

            start = (line[push_back(_val, _1)] | ignore) % eol;
        }

    private:
        qi::rule<It> ignore;
        qi::rule<It, structs::Record1()> line;
        qi::rule<It, structs::Records1()> start;
    };

    template <typename It>
    struct Parser4 : qi::grammar<It, structs::Records2()>
    {
        Parser4() : Parser4::base_type(start) {
            using namespace qi;
            using boost::phoenix::push_back;

            line = '[' >> stream >> ']'
                >> " - " >> double_ >> " s"
                >> " => String: "  >> raw[+graph];

            ignore = *~char_("\r\n");

            start = (line[push_back(_val, _1)] | ignore) % eol;
        }

    private:
        qi::rule<It> ignore;
        qi::rule<It, structs::Record2()> line;
        qi::rule<It, structs::Records2()> start;
    };
}

template<typename Parser, typename Container>
Container parse_seek(It b, It e, const std::string& message)
{
    static const Parser parser;

    Container records;

    boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t0 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    parse(b, e, *boost::spirit::repository::qi::seek[parser], records);
    boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto elapsed = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::milliseconds>(t1 - t0);
    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() << " ms (" << message << ")\n";

    return records;
}

template<typename Parser, typename Container>
Container parse_ignoring(It b, It e, const std::string& message)
{
    static const Parser parser;

    Container records;

    boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t0 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    parse(b, e, parser, records);
    boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto elapsed = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::milliseconds>(t1 - t0);
    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() << " ms (" << message << ")\n";

    return records;
}

static const std::string input1 = "[2018-Mar-01 00:00:00.000000] - 1.000 s => String: Valid_string\n";
static const std::string input2 = "[2018-Mar-02 00:00:00.000000] - 2.000 s => I dont care\n";
static std::string input("");

int main() {
    const int N1 = 10;
    const int N2 = 100000;

    input.reserve(N1 * (input1.size() + N2*input2.size()));

    for (int i = N1; i--;)
    {
        input += input1;

        for (int j = N2; j--;)
            input += input2;
    }

    const auto records1 = parse_seek<QiParsers::Parser1<It>, structs::Records1>(input.begin(), input.end(), "std::string + seek");
    const auto records2 = parse_seek<QiParsers::Parser2<It>, structs::Records2>(input.begin(), input.end(), "stream + seek");

    const auto records3 = parse_ignoring<QiParsers::Parser3<It>, structs::Records1>(input.begin(), input.end(), "std::string + ignoring");
    const auto records4 = parse_ignoring<QiParsers::Parser4<It>, structs::Records2>(input.begin(), input.end(), "stream + ignoring");

    return 0;
}
```

The results in the console are:

```
Elapsed time: 1445 ms (std::string + seek)
Elapsed time: 21519 ms (stream + seek)
Elapsed time: 860 ms (std::string + ignoring)
Elapsed time: 19046 ms (stream + ignoring)
```

Comment: Ha, this is a totum revolutum problem, In case you set N1=100000 and N2=0 (a lot of matching lines only) the stream+seek parser beats the other 3 options, including the ignoring line! I would love to understand this, Still my assumption was that stream was appending not matching dates, but after this last test I am just totally lost. I understand that std::string cases are penalized due to allocation of 1e6 str format dates. But why stream+ignore version is penalized here? Should I give up or there is any explanation?

Comment: "stream+ignore" means "(parse-date-time&discard) + ignore". As my answer outlines (see "Summary") the cost of parsing is the main cost here, even though I [expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49502728/several-matches-in-a-one-pass-parser#comment86066779_49503266) it to be on par with the string allocations. Therefore the fact that the parses are being done even when the line is discarded hurts doubly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, in the code posted, 70%¹ of time is spent in the stream's underflow operation.

[image]

I <strike>haven't looked into /why/ that is, but instead</strike>² wrote a few naive implementations to see whether I could do better. First steps:

> ² **Update** I've since [analyzed it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49710367/85371) and provided a [PR](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/pull/383).
>
> The improvement created by that PR does not affect the bottom line in this particular case (see **SUMMARY**)

- drop `operator>>` for `Timestamp` (we won't be using that)
- replace all instances of `'[' >> stream >> ']'` with the alternative `'[' >> raw[*~char_(']')] >> ']'` so that we will always be using the trait to transform the iterator range into the attribute type (`std::string` or `Timestamp`)

Now, we implement the `assign_to_attribute_from_iterators<structs::Timestamp, It>` trait:

### Variant 1: Array Source

```
template <typename It>
struct assign_to_attribute_from_iterators<structs::Timestamp, It, void> {
    static inline void call(It f, It l, structs::Timestamp& time) {
        boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::array_source> stream(f, l);

        struct std::tm tm;
        if (stream >> std::get_time(&tm, "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S") >> time.ms)
            time.date = std::mktime(&tm);
        else throw "Parse failure";
    }
};
```

Profiling with callgrind: [image] (click for zoom)

It does improve considerably, probably because we make the assumption that the underlying char-buffer is contiguous, where the Spirit implementation cannot make that assumption. We spend ~42% of the time in `time_get`.

Roughly speaking, 25% of time is devoted to locale stuff, of which a worrying **~20%** is spent doing dynamic casts :(

### Variant 2: Array Source with re-use

Same, but reusing a static stream instance to see whether it makes a significant difference:

```
static boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::array_source> s_stream;

template <typename It>
struct assign_to_attribute_from_iterators<structs::Timestamp, It, void> {
    static inline void call(It f, It l, structs::Timestamp& time) {
        struct std::tm tm;

        if (s_stream.is_open()) s_stream.close();
        s_stream.clear();
        boost::iostreams::array_source as(f, l);
        s_stream.open(as);

        if (s_stream >> std::get_time(&tm, "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S") >> time.ms)
            time.date = std::mktime(&tm);
        else throw "Parse failure";
    }
};
```

Profiling reveals is no significant difference).

### Variant 3: `strptime` and `strtod`/`from_chars`

Let's see if dropping to C-level reduces the locale hurt:

```
template <typename It>
struct assign_to_attribute_from_iterators<structs::Timestamp, It, void> {
    static inline void call(It f, It l, structs::Timestamp& time) {
        struct std::tm tm;
        auto remain = strptime(&*f, "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm);
        time.date = std::mktime(&tm);

    #if __has_include(<charconv>) || __cpp_lib_to_chars >= 201611
        auto result = std::from_chars(&*f, &*l, time.ms); // using <charconv> from c++17
    #else
        char* end;
        time.ms = std::strtod(remain, &end);

        assert(end > remain);
        static_cast<void>(l); // unused
    #endif
    }
};
```

> As you can see, using `strtod` is a bit suboptimal here. The input range is bounded, but there's no way to tell `strtod` about that. I have not been able to profile the `from_chars` approach, which is strictly safer because it doesn't have this issue.
>
> In practice for your sample code it is safe to use `strtod` because we know the input buffer is NUL-terminated.

[image]

Here you can see that parsing the date-time is still a factor of concern:

- mktime   15.58 %
- strptime 40.54 %
- strtod    5.88 %

But all in all the difference is less egregious now:

- Parser1: 14.17 %
- Parser2: 43.44 %
- Parser3:  5.69 %
- Parser4: 35.49 %

### Variant 4: Boost DateTime Again

Interestingly, the performance of the "lowlevel" C-APIs is not far from using the much more highlevel Boost `posix_time::ptime` functions:

```
template <typename It>
struct assign_to_attribute_from_iterators<structs::Timestamp, It, void> {
    static inline void call(It f, It l, structs::Timestamp& time) {
        time.date = to_time_t(boost::posix_time::time_from_string(std::string(f,l)));
    }
};
```

> This might sacrifice some precision, [according to the docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#ptime_from_string):
>
> [image]

[image]

Here, the total time spent parsing date and time is 68%. The relative speeds of the parsers are close to the last ones:

- Parser1: 12.33 %
- Parser2: 43.86 %
- Parser3:  5.22 %
- Parser4: 37.43 %

## SUMMARY

All in all, it turns out that storing the strings seems faster, even if you risk allocating more. I've done a very simple check whether this could be down to [SSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring) by increasing the length of the substring:

```
static const std::string input1 = "[2018-Mar-01 00:01:02.012345 THWARTING THE SMALL STRING OPTIMIZATION HERE THIS WON'T FIT, NO DOUBT] - 1.000 s => String: Valid_string\n";
static const std::string input2 = "[2018-Mar-02 00:01:02.012345 THWARTING THE SMALL STRING OPTIMIZATION HERE THIS WON'T FIT, NO DOUBT] - 2.000 s => I dont care\n";
```

There was no significant impact, so that leaves the parsing itself.

It seems clear that either you will want to delay parsing the time (`Parser3` is by far the quickest) **or** should go with the time-tested Boost `posix_time` functions.

### LISTING

Here's the combined benchmark code I used. A few things changed:

- added some sanity check output (to avoid testing nonsensical code)
- made the iterator generic (changing to `char*` has no significant effect on performance in optimized builds)
- the above variants are all manually switchable in the code by changing `#if 1` to `#if 0` in the right spots
- reduced N1/N2 for convenience

I've liberally used C++14 because the purpose of the code was to find bottlenecks. Any wisdom gained can be backported relatively easily after the profiling.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/738930696628bb96)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_seek.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono/chrono.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#if __has_include(<charconv>) || __cpp_lib_to_chars >= 201611
#    include <charconv> // not supported yet until GCC 8
#endif

namespace structs {
    struct Timestamp {
        std::time_t date;
        double ms;
    };

    struct Record1 {
        std::string date;
        double time;
        std::string str;
    };

    struct Record2 {
        Timestamp date;
        double time;
        std::string str;
    };

    typedef std::vector<Record1> Records1;
    typedef std::vector<Record2> Records2;
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(structs::Record1,
        (std::string, date)
        (double, time)
        (std::string, str))

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(structs::Record2,
        (structs::Timestamp, date)
        (double, time)
        (std::string, str))

namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace traits {
    template <typename It>
    struct assign_to_attribute_from_iterators<std::string, It, void> {
        static inline void call(It f, It l, std::string& attr) {
            attr = std::string(&*f, std::distance(f,l));
        }
    };

    static boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::array_source> s_stream;

    template <typename It>
    struct assign_to_attribute_from_iterators<structs::Timestamp, It, void> {
        static inline void call(It f, It l, structs::Timestamp& time) {
#if 1
            time.date = to_time_t(boost::posix_time::time_from_string(std::string(f,l)));
#elif 1
            struct std::tm tm;
            boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::array_source> stream(f, l);

            if (stream >> std::get_time(&tm, "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S") >> time.ms)
                time.date = std::mktime(&tm);
            else
                throw "Parse failure";
#elif 1
            struct std::tm tm;
            if (s_stream.is_open()) s_stream.close();
            s_stream.clear();
            boost::iostreams::array_source as(f, l);
            s_stream.open(as);

            if (s_stream >> std::get_time(&tm, "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S") >> time.ms)
                time.date = std::mktime(&tm);
            else
                throw "Parse failure";
#else
            struct std::tm tm;
            auto remain = strptime(&*f, "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm);
            time.date = std::mktime(&tm);

        #if __has_include(<charconv>) || __cpp_lib_to_chars >= 201611
            auto result = std::from_chars(&*f, &*l, time.ms); // using <charconv> from c++17
        #else
            char* end;
            time.ms = std::strtod(remain, &end);

            assert(end > remain);
            static_cast<void>(l); // unused
        #endif
#endif
        }
    };
} } }

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace QiParsers {
    template <typename It>
    struct Parser1 : qi::grammar<It, structs::Record1()>
    {
        Parser1() : Parser1::base_type(start) {
            using namespace qi;

            start = '[' >> raw[*~char_(']')] >> ']'
                >> " - " >> double_ >> " s"
                >> " => String: "  >> raw[+graph]
                >> eol;
        }

    private:
        qi::rule<It, structs::Record1()> start;
    };

    template <typename It>
    struct Parser2 : qi::grammar<It, structs::Record2()>
    {
        Parser2() : Parser2::base_type(start) {
            using namespace qi;

            start = '[' >> raw[*~char_(']')] >> ']'
                >> " - " >> double_ >> " s"
                >> " => String: "  >> raw[+graph]
                >> eol;
        }

    private:
        qi::rule<It, structs::Record2()> start;
    };

    template <typename It>
    struct Parser3 : qi::grammar<It, structs::Records1()>
    {
        Parser3() : Parser3::base_type(start) {
            using namespace qi;
            using boost::phoenix::push_back;

            line = '[' >> raw[*~char_(']')] >> ']'
                >> " - " >> double_ >> " s"
                >> " => String: "  >> raw[+graph];

            ignore = *~char_("\r\n");

            start = (line[push_back(_val, _1)] | ignore) % eol;
        }

    private:
        qi::rule<It> ignore;
        qi::rule<It, structs::Record1()> line;
        qi::rule<It, structs::Records1()> start;
    };

    template <typename It>
    struct Parser4 : qi::grammar<It, structs::Records2()>
    {
        Parser4() : Parser4::base_type(start) {
            using namespace qi;
            using boost::phoenix::push_back;

            line = '[' >> raw[*~char_(']')] >> ']'
                >> " - " >> double_ >> " s"
                >> " => String: "  >> raw[+graph];

            ignore = *~char_("\r\n");

            start = (line[push_back(_val, _1)] | ignore) % eol;
        }

    private:
        qi::rule<It> ignore;
        qi::rule<It, structs::Record2()> line;
        qi::rule<It, structs::Records2()> start;
    };
}

template <typename Parser> static const Parser s_instance {};

template<template <typename> class Parser, typename Container, typename It>
Container parse_seek(It b, It e, const std::string& message)
{
    Container records;

    auto const t0 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    parse(b, e, *boost::spirit::repository::qi::seek[s_instance<Parser<It> >], records);
    auto const t1 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto elapsed = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::milliseconds>(t1 - t0);
    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() << " ms (" << message << ")\n";

    return records;
}

template<template <typename> class Parser, typename Container, typename It>
Container parse_ignoring(It b, It e, const std::string& message)
{
    Container records;

    auto const t0 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    parse(b, e, s_instance<Parser<It> >, records);
    auto const t1 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto elapsed = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::milliseconds>(t1 - t0);
    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() << " ms (" << message << ")\n";

    return records;
}

static const std::string input1 = "[2018-Mar-01 00:01:02.012345] - 1.000 s => String: Valid_string\n";
static const std::string input2 = "[2018-Mar-02 00:01:02.012345] - 2.000 s => I dont care\n";

std::string prepare_input() {
    std::string input;
    const int N1 = 10;
    const int N2 = 1000;

    input.reserve(N1 * (input1.size() + N2*input2.size()));

    for (int i = N1; i--;) {
        input += input1;
        for (int j = N2; j--;)
            input += input2;
    }

    return input;
}

int main() {
    auto const input = prepare_input();

    auto f = input.data(), l = f + input.length();

    for (auto& r: parse_seek<QiParsers::Parser1, structs::Records1>(f, l, "std::string + seek")) {
        std::cout << r.date << "\n";
        break;
    }
    for (auto& r: parse_seek<QiParsers::Parser2, structs::Records2>(f, l, "stream + seek")) {
        auto tm = *std::localtime(&r.date.date);
        std::cout << std::put_time(&tm, "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S") << "\n";
        break;
    }
    for (auto& r: parse_ignoring<QiParsers::Parser3, structs::Records1>(f, l, "std::string + ignoring")) {
        std::cout << r.date << "\n";
        break;
    }
    for (auto& r: parse_ignoring<QiParsers::Parser4, structs::Records2>(f, l, "stream + ignoring")) {
        auto tm = *std::localtime(&r.date.date);
        std::cout << std::put_time(&tm, "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S") << "\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

Printing something like

```
Elapsed time: 14 ms (std::string + seek)
2018-Mar-01 00:01:02.012345
Elapsed time: 29 ms (stream + seek)
2018-Mar-01 00:01:02
Elapsed time: 2 ms (std::string + ignoring)
2018-Mar-01 00:01:02.012345
Elapsed time: 22 ms (stream + ignoring)
2018-Mar-01 00:01:02
```

---

¹ all percentages are relative to *total* program cost. That *does* skew the percentages (the 70% mentioned would be even worse if the non-stream parser tests weren't taken into account), but the numbers are a good enough guide for relative comparions *within* a test run.

Comment: PS. I should have removed all mention of `stream` from the benchmark code/output because all variants use the trait approach.

Comment: One way to win a bit if many lines are ignored, is to avoid parsing the date for those lines. This is exemplified in [the results in this other benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49702941/85371)

Answer (score 1):

The `stream` parser ends up doing this:

```
    template <typename Iterator, typename Context
      , typename Skipper, typename Attribute>
    bool parse(Iterator& first, Iterator const& last
      , Context& /*context*/, Skipper const& skipper
      , Attribute& attr_) const
    {
        typedef qi::detail::iterator_source<Iterator> source_device;
        typedef boost::iostreams::stream<source_device> instream;

        qi::skip_over(first, last, skipper);

        instream in(first, last);           // copies 'first'
        in >> attr_;                        // use existing operator>>()

        // advance the iterator if everything is ok
        if (in) {
            if (!in.eof()) {
                std::streamsize pos = in.tellg();
                std::advance(first, pos);
            } else {
                first = last;
            }
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

The `detail::iterator_source<Iterator>` device is a costly abstraction because it needs to be generic. It needs to be able support forward-only iterators¹.

### Specializing For Random Access Iterators

I've created a Pull Request to specialize on random-access iterators: https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/pull/383 which specializes `iterator_source` for random-access iterators:

```
std::streamsize read (char_type* s, std::streamsize n)
{
    if (first == last)
        return -1;

    n = std::min(std::distance(first, last), n);

    // copy_n is only part of c++11, so emulate it
    std::copy(first, first + n, s);
    first += n;
    pos += n;

    return n;
}
```

Without the specialization we can observe these timings: **[Interactive Plot.ly](https://plot.ly/~sehe/7/)**

(100 samples, confidence interval 0.95)

```
benchmarking std::string + seek     mean:   31.9222 ms std dev: 228.862  μs
benchmarking std::string + ignoring mean:   16.1855 ms std dev: 257.903  μs

benchmarking stream      + seek     mean: 1075.46   ms std dev:  22.23   ms
benchmarking stream      + ignoring mean: 1064.41   ms std dev:  26.7218 ms
```

[image]

With the specialization we can observe these timings: **[Interactive Plot.ly](https://plot.ly/~sehe/9/)**

```
benchmarking std::string + seek     mean:  31.8703 ms std dev: 529.196  μs
benchmarking std::string + ignoring mean:  15.913  ms std dev: 848.514  μs

benchmarking stream      + seek     mean: 436.263  ms std dev:  19.4035 ms
benchmarking stream      + ignoring mean: 419.539  ms std dev:  20.0511 ms
```

[image]

### Nonius Benchmark Code

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_seek.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono/chrono.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

namespace structs {
    struct Timestamp {
        std::time_t date;
        double ms;

        friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& stream, Timestamp& time)
        {
            struct std::tm tm;

            if (stream >> std::get_time(&tm, "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S") >> time.ms)
                time.date = std::mktime(&tm);

            return stream;
        }
    };

    struct Record1 {
        std::string date;
        double time;
        std::string str;
    };

    struct Record2 {
        Timestamp date;
        double time;
        std::string str;
    };

    typedef std::vector<Record1> Records1;
    typedef std::vector<Record2> Records2;
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(structs::Record1,
        (std::string, date)
        (double, time)
        (std::string, str))

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(structs::Record2,
        (structs::Timestamp, date)
        (double, time)
        (std::string, str))

namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace traits {
    template <typename It>
    struct assign_to_attribute_from_iterators<std::string, It, void> {
        static inline void call(It f, It l, std::string& attr) {
            attr = std::string(&*f, std::distance(f,l));
        }
    };
} } }

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace QiParsers {
    template <typename It>
    struct Parser1 : qi::grammar<It, structs::Record1()>
    {
        Parser1() : Parser1::base_type(start) {
            using namespace qi;

            start = '[' >> raw[*~char_(']')] >> ']'
                >> " - " >> double_ >> " s"
                >> " => String: "  >> raw[+graph]
                >> eol;
        }

    private:
        qi::rule<It, structs::Record1()> start;
    };

    template <typename It>
    struct Parser2 : qi::grammar<It, structs::Record2()>
    {
        Parser2() : Parser2::base_type(start) {
            using namespace qi;

            start = '[' >> stream >> ']'
                >> " - " >> double_ >> " s"
                >> " => String: "  >> raw[+graph]
                >> eol;
        }

    private:
        qi::rule<It, structs::Record2()> start;
    };

    template <typename It>
    struct Parser3 : qi::grammar<It, structs::Records1()>
    {
        Parser3() : Parser3::base_type(start) {
            using namespace qi;
            using boost::phoenix::push_back;

            line = '[' >> raw[*~char_(']')] >> ']'
                >> " - " >> double_ >> " s"
                >> " => String: "  >> raw[+graph];

            ignore = *~char_("\r\n");

            start = (line[push_back(_val, _1)] | ignore) % eol;
        }

    private:
        qi::rule<It> ignore;
        qi::rule<It, structs::Record1()> line;
        qi::rule<It, structs::Records1()> start;
    };

    template <typename It>
    struct Parser4 : qi::grammar<It, structs::Records2()>
    {
        Parser4() : Parser4::base_type(start) {
            using namespace qi;
            using boost::phoenix::push_back;

            line = '[' >> stream >> ']'
                >> " - " >> double_ >> " s"
                >> " => String: "  >> raw[+graph];

            ignore = *~char_("\r\n");

            start = (line[push_back(_val, _1)] | ignore) % eol;
        }

    private:
        qi::rule<It> ignore;
        qi::rule<It, structs::Record2()> line;
        qi::rule<It, structs::Records2()> start;
    };
}

typedef boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point time_point;

template<template <typename> class Parser, typename Container, typename It>
Container parse_seek(It b, It e, const std::string& message)
{
    static const Parser<It> s_instance;
    Container records;

    time_point const t0 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    parse(b, e, *boost::spirit::repository::qi::seek[s_instance], records);
    time_point const t1 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::milliseconds>(t1 - t0).count() << " ms (" << message << ")\n";

    return records;
}

template<template <typename> class Parser, typename Container, typename It>
Container parse_ignoring(It b, It e, const std::string& message)
{
    static const Parser<It> s_instance;
    Container records;

    time_point const t0 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    parse(b, e, s_instance, records);
    time_point const t1 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::milliseconds>(t1 - t0).count() << " ms (" << message << ")\n";

    return records;
}

static const std::string input1 = "[2018-Mar-01 00:01:02.012345] - 1.000 s => String: Valid_string\n";
static const std::string input2 = "[2018-Mar-02 00:01:02.012345] - 2.000 s => I dont care\n";

std::string prepare_input() {
    std::string input;
    const int N1 = 10;
    const int N2 = 10000;

    input.reserve(N1 * (input1.size() + N2*input2.size()));

    for (int i = N1; i--;) {
        input += input1;
        for (int j = N2; j--;)
            input += input2;
    }

    return input;
}

void verify(structs::Records1 const& records) {
    if (records.empty())
        std::cout << "Oops nothing parsed\n";
    else {
        structs::Record1 const& r = *records.begin();
        std::cout << r.date << "\n";
    }
}

void verify(structs::Records2 const& records) {
    if (records.empty())
        std::cout << "Oops nothing parsed\n";
    else {
        structs::Record2 const& r = *records.begin();
        auto tm = *std::localtime(&r.date.date);
        std::cout << std::put_time(&tm, "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S") << " " << r.date.ms << "\n";
    }
}

static std::string const input = prepare_input();

#define NONIUS_RUNNER
#include <nonius/benchmark.h++>
#include <nonius/main.h++>

NONIUS_BENCHMARK("std::string + seek", [] {
    char const* f = input.data();
    char const* l = f + input.length();
    //std::string::const_iterator f = input.begin(), l = input.end();
    verify(parse_seek<QiParsers::Parser1,     structs::Records1>(f, l, "std::string + seek"));
})

NONIUS_BENCHMARK("stream + seek", [] {
    char const* f = input.data();
    char const* l = f + input.length();
    //std::string::const_iterator f = input.begin(), l = input.end();
    verify(parse_seek<QiParsers::Parser2,     structs::Records2>(f, l, "stream + seek"));
})

NONIUS_BENCHMARK("std::string + ignoring", [] {
    char const* f = input.data();
    char const* l = f + input.length();
    //std::string::const_iterator f = input.begin(), l = input.end();
    verify(parse_ignoring<QiParsers::Parser3, structs::Records1>(f, l, "std::string + ignoring"));
})

NONIUS_BENCHMARK("stream + ignoring", [] {
    char const* f = input.data();
    char const* l = f + input.length();
    //std::string::const_iterator f = input.begin(), l = input.end();
    verify(parse_ignoring<QiParsers::Parser4, structs::Records2>(f, l, "stream + ignoring"));
})
```

---

¹ e.g. when the parser's iterator happens to be a `multi_pass_adaptor<InputIterator>`, which is a separate monster on its own: [Boost spirit memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504267/boost-spirit-memory-leak/40515812#40515812)

Comment: Real nice job! I hope boost accepts your PR for v1.67. I would be glad of having cooperated in that (even so indirectly), althought my only value has been counting seconds with my fingers ;-). Thank you again for your help and explanations. I have really learnt a lot about spirit and how it works.

Comment: So, there's this, and then the idea to use "dateparts" to cut locale costs and postpone actual calculations with of `mktime`, should get you decent performance if you choose to actually parse the date

Comment: Just as a final remark: You should try this same benchmark with something like N1=10000 and N2=0 if you still feel in the mood. In this case stream parsers beat up absolubtely string parsers. Should we call an exorcist or is there a not devil involved explanation to this?

Comment: I don't think there's anything unexplained (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49693376/why-does-using-a-stream-in-boost-spirit-penalize-performance-so-much/49710367?noredirect=1#comment86419513_49702675)). You can, of course, verify that with a profiler. In the case of "only matching lines" it will be additionally helped by prefetch and branch prediction.

Comment: Upps, sorry, I should have read your post twice at least. I am given to forget about cpu optimization (cache, not branching...) and look for weird explanations.